# boundingRectWithSize: for UITextView that wraps around UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a big `UITextview` and a `UIImageView`. The text wraps around the image to its left. However I need to calculate the height this view will be after it wraps. But when I do `boundingRectWithSize`: it returns the size for a `textView` that is a rectangular shape. How do I accomplish this?

```
CGRect newRect = imageView.frame;
newRect.origin.x -= 15;
newRect.origin.y -= 15;
newRect.size.width += 15;
newRect.size.height += 15;

UIBezierPath *imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:newRect];
introMessage.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
```